# What is the utility of the expression “int(a[-1])” in Python?

Tags: python, char

i have found this code but i do not understand the meaning of this int(ean8[-1]).

```
from odoo.tests import common

class TestBarcodeNomenclature(common.TransactionCase):

    def test_ean8_checksum(self):
        barcode_nomenclature = self.env['barcode.nomenclature']
        ean8 = "87111125"
        checksum = barcode_nomenclature.ean8_checksum(ean8)
        self.assertEqual(checksum, int(ean8[-1]))
        checksum = barcode_nomenclature.ean8_checksum("8711112")
        self.assertEqual(checksum, -1)
        checksum = barcode_nomenclature.ean8_checksum("871111256")
        self.assertEqual(checksum, -1)
```

Comment: what do you get when you `print(int("87111125"[-1]))`?

Comment: `a[-1]` takes last element of list, a string is an implicit list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `int(ean8[-1])` takes the last character `[-1]` of the string `ean8` and converts it into an integer to allow further operations, that most require an integer (instead of a string) to be executed.

This is due to the fact that the barcode is present in form of a string, or a sequence of characters. Thats because you can retrieve the last character of a string via index call `[-1]`. The `-1` takes the last element of the list.